# Streaming from a Delta Live Tables in databrick to kafka instance

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, databricks, delta-live-tables

I have the following live table

[image]

And i'm looking to write that into a stream to be written back into my kafka source.

I've seen in the apache spark docs that I can use writeStream ( I've used readStream to get it out of my kafka stream already ). But how do I transform the table into the medium it needs so it can use this?

I'm fairly new to both kafka and the data world so any further explanation's are welcome here.

```
writeStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
    .option("topic", "updates")
    .start()
```

Thanks in Advance,

Ben

I've seen in the apache spark docs that I can use writeStream ( I've used readStream to get it out of my kafka stream already ). But how do I transform the table into the medium it needs so it can use this?I'm fairly new to both kafka and the data world so any further explanation's are welcome here.

```
writeStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
    .option("topic", "updates")
    .start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of *right now*, Delta Live Tables can only write data as a Delta table - it's not possible to write in other formats.  You can implement a workaround by creating a Databricks workflow that consist of two tasks (with dependencies or not depending if the pipeline is triggered or not):

- DLT Pipeline that will do the actual data processing
- A task (easiest way to do with notebook) that will read a table generated by DLT as a stream and write its content into Kafka, with something like that:

```py
df = spark.readStream.format("delta").table("database.table_name")
(df.write.format("kafka").option("kafka....", "")
  .trigger(availableNow=True) # if it's not continuous
  .start()
)
```

P.S. If you have solution architect or customer success engineer attached to your Databricks account, you can communicate this requirement to them for product prioritization.

Comment: Okay this on the right track, hoping for a complete noob question here, but I have the gold table defined as in my screenshot, but now getting Table or View not found.  I have this in my pipeline after the gold build step as a python notebook.

Comment: you need to use database name provided in the `target` configuration of your pipeline, and table name without `LIVE.`

Answer (score 0):

The transformation is done after the read stream process is started

```py
read_df = spark.readStream.format('kafka') ... .... # other options

processed_df = read_df.withColumn('some column', some_calculation )

processed_df.writeStream.format('parquet') ... .... # other options
                         .start()
```

The spark documentation is helpful and detailed but some articles are not for beginners. You can look on youtube or read articles to help you get started like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RLfTxtgeVhM)

Comment: this is for a Spark code, not for the Delta Live Tables...